# How to make a system disk image of windows 10 (GPT)?

Tags: windows-10, backup, mbr, restore, gpt

I used to make a backup of my system partition (Win 7 MBR) with drivexml, so when something goes wrong I could restore my image along with progs and settings.
Now I got new ssd and installed win 10 GPT and when I tried to use drivexml it doesn't recognize the the system disk at all. and I found out there are 2 more hidden partitions than used to be, 100mb and 128mb.

Now, Can I use the drivexml or it doesn't work with my new enviroment?
Is there any other backup software I could use in my case? -Dealing with gpt system- Or should I re-install my system using MBR?

Comment: I have been using Macrium Reflect Free for years, very happy with it.

Comment: Have you tried to google this? The keyword is "disk cloning".

Comment: @gronostaj Yes I did. but I didn't find similar case to mine. I'll search deeper

Comment: Your case isn't particularly unusual. It's the default and pretty common nowadays actually. All competent, modern disk cloning programs will support it.

Comment: Till now I only found cloning to different disk (new hard) not to an image to restore later. I'll post any updates in case of having a solution